# Optimising a palette mapping shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to optimise a palette mapping shader written in GLSL (running on iPhone). My implementation is certainly naive but I'm completely new to OpenGL... Here's a summary of how it looks:

```
#define COLOR_BLACK vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
#define COLOR_WHITE vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(... total of 16 colors)

highp vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, samplePos );

highp float distances[16];
distances[0] = distance(color, COLOR_BLACK);
distances[1] = distance(color, COLOR_WHITE);
(... total of 16 distance calculations)

(... find smallest colour distance)

mediump vec4 finalColor;
if (colorDistance == distances[0]) {
    finalColor = COLOR_BLACK;
} else if (colorDistance == distances[1]) {
    finalColor = COLOR_WHITE;
(... total of 16 comparisons)

gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

This works fine but it's rather slow. I'm sure I'm not making an effective use of OpenGL here :)

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you preprocess your input texture to replace texels by your palette colors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a (small) 3D texture in nearest filtering mode as a lookup table.

#### Update due to comment

If 3D textures are not available you can use one larger sized 1D texture, again in nearest filtering mode, and address 3D texels the same way you'd address them in a flat array, i.e.

```
texel_index(x,y,z) = x*width*height + y*width + z;
```

Comment: Not all devices (eg. my iPad) support 3D textures (only cube-textures)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this effect is by rounding/flooring. So you get (untested):

```
highp vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, samplePos );
gl_FragColor = floor(color*2.0) * 0.5;
```

You might want to play around with the factor 2.

Comment: But I am trying to map to a given fixed palette, i.e. I have a list of 16 RGB values and mapping each pixel to the closest colour in this palette ...

Comment: The typical method is to expand the initial value (from 0-1 to 0-16), then lerp between the floor and ceiling (for 13.2, 13 and 14) using the fractional part (0.2). That relies, however, on the values being stored in an array, not macros.

Comment: The reason why I mention this method is that conditionals generally are slow (in my experience), so using a function (or texture as datenwolf said) to do the trick is often faster.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of palette are you mapping to? Is it just sixteen random colours or is there a pattern to them?

Supposing the 16 colours is, say, eight colours plus bright or dark then you could convert the incoming RGB to YUV (or any other luminance-oriented space), make a single judgment on the Y channel then turn the UV into a 2d test via a single texture lookup. If the eight colours were on or off for red, green and blue then you can do the 2d test without a lookup.

If you just want a discrete look then something like Jaxan's rounding-within-components is probably the smartest thing.